# Remove entire element from dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I'm having a dictionary like so...

```
[

"113": SellerApp.Product(name: "aaaa", id: "113", images: [SellerApp.ProductImage(myId: "996", url: http://myApp.com/public/uploads/products/123_113_1_image_123456789, isDefault: true)], theRate: "234", quantity: "17", sku: "Hdjsu", prdCateg: "tr123", prodDescr: "Gdhd", mrp: "520"), 

"101": SellerApp.Product(name: "dfg", id: "101", images: [SellerApp.ProductImage(myId: "982", url: http://myApp.com/public/uploads/products/563_101_1_image_1011121314, isDefault: true)], theRate: "123", quantity: "7", sku: "345", prdCateg: "tr123", prodDescr: "Test", mrp: "234")

]
```

Now each of these values are associated with a tableviewcell. So when I delete the particular cell, all the values associated with it should get deleted. So if I delete the 1st cell, then in the above snippet, all  values from `"113": SellerApp.Product(name: "aa...` to `mrp: "520")` should get deleted.

I tried something like this...

```
    for (index, dict) in self.appDelegate.myDictionary1.enumerated() {

        if dict.key == (self.appDelegate.commonArrForselectedItems[indexPath.section].id) {

            self.appDelegate.myDictionary1.removeValue(forKey: self.appDelegate.commonArrForselectedItems[indexPath.section].id)

        }
    }
```

But this seems to delete the id itself and all the remaining values sort of persists. How can I delete from the dictionary all the values associated with this id..?

Comment: Why you don't delete values in tableView's didSelectIndexPath method at clicked Index?

Comment: It seems there is some issue with how I'm deleting...

Answer (score 0):

@bvt, try deleting value like below code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    yourArrayName.remove(at: indexPath.row)
}
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: No..I don't want to delete the whole array..Its just the dictionary elements that I want to delete...

Comment: Func remove takes Dictionary.Index as parameter, not Int.

Answer (score 0):

Assume our dictionary is:

```
var deck = ["Queen": "Spades", "Jack": "Hearts", "King": "Clubs", "Ace": "Diamonds"]
```

If we want to remove the element with `key = "Jack"`, we need to write this:

```
let index = deck.index(forKey: "Jack")
deck.remove(at: index!)
```

To remove by index:

```
let index = deck.index(deck.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
deck.remove(at: index)
```

However, you should remember that dictionaries aren't ordered collections. They don't maintain the order of elements. In our example, although the second elements is the one with `key = "King"` by looking to the code, the order is changed after hashing as follows:

```
["Jack": "Hearts", "Ace": "Diamonds", "Queen": "Spades", "King": "Clubs"]
```

Thus if you remove second element, not the element with `"King" : Clubs` will go but `"Queen": "Spades"` will.

Comment: Thanks @Dorukhan Arslan actually things were working properly already. Debugging revealed that. My bad!..:)